# *ngFor nor recognizing object properties

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/1tRLveSyNz8?t=6072) (I set the time to be where my problem starts). 
I have a problem locally when he removes all elements from `posts` variable and sets it to an empty array.

Here's the `post-list.component.ts` just in case:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})

export class PostListComponent {
  posts = [];
}
```

In `post-list.component.html`:

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ post.title }} <-HERE
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>
      {{ post.content }} <- HERE
    </p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p class="mat-body-1 info-text" *ngIf="posts.length <= 0">No posts added</p>
```

where I put `<- HERE` is where the `.title` and `.content` next to `post` are underlined.
When I click the error it says:
`Identifier 'title' is not defined. 'never' does not contain such a memberng`

But the guy in tutorial doesn't have that error. I presume that a lot has changed in two years of development on node.js / angular. 
I also get that error when I open the site (localhost:4200).

Why is this happening? How can I easily overcome this simple error when the array is empty?
I would also like to not do any quickfixes like putting one empty `post` in `posts`. I'd rather understand how it works and find a proper, easily understandable way to overcome this in this new version of environment.

As I noticed the guy in this tutorial is working on the latest versions from 2016. Two years after that he uploaded this part of the course to youtube, and it's fine for me for now. You can hear about it in the first couple of minutes of the video. Here are the versions I'm currently using:

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1101.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.1
@angular-devkit/core            11.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.1.1
@angular/cli                    11.1.1
@schematics/angular             11.1.1
@schematics/update              0.1101.1
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.3
```

I'm pretty new to all this tho I'm not new to programming, but I don't really know what to search on the internet to get the solution for this little problem.

**EDIT 1:**
As requested, [here's the same thing in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e5qgos?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Take a look at `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html`.
It doesn't show the error here, but here are some screenshots from my project just to prove I'm not faking this:

[image]
[image]

I also tried replacing the `.html` file locally, pasting the code from the stackblitzs' `app.component.html`, but the same thing happends. Squiggly red underline under `.title` in `{{ post.tilte }}`

Comment: Looks fine to me. I doubt its an issue with versions of node or angular. Can you reproduce this elsewhere for eg, stackblitz? If `posts` is empty, then as Max says in the video, the entire `mat-accordion` will not even be rendered on the DOM. Seems strange that you would get that error in this case. Are you sure that error is coming from this component?

Comment: It says `'never' does not contain such a memberng`, what is this `never` object?

I'm not sure what's wrong, but you can try to write `{{ post?.title }}` and `{{ post?.content }}` to temporarily fix it.

Comment: Ok, I added the `EDIT 1` to the question. This should answer both your questions @Nicholas, @mahvai. Even in stackblitz there's no error, but locally there is. What could I have done with the environment to get this error? I just (litelarly) reinstalled windows because I had some other errors with this because I tried some other tutorials months before, and I wanted to follow this tutorial, so instead of figuring out 100 bugs I reinstalled everything and just followed the tutorial step by step :/

Comment: Adding a stackblitz, where it works like expected, is the opposite of reproducing the issue.

Comment: @JSONDerulo, well... that kinda is the point. This code works fine on stackblitz and in this guy's tutorial from probably 2016, but I get some errors. That is the issue. So it's not the opposite of reproducing the issue. It proves my point / my issue. I hoped that I'd get the same issue on stackblitz but I didn't, and have no clue what is happening to my environment so that it acts so strange. That's why I'm asking for help here. I thought that was clear.

Comment: You need to set up a stackblitz where it doesn't work, that's the whole point of setting up a stackblitz.

Comment: Seems like it could be an issue with some setting in VS code. Could you try defining `posts` as `posts: any = [];`.

Comment: HOLY MACARONI, IT WORKS @NicholasK! My environment is probably setup so that it doesn't do the `:any=` magic automatically somehow. I don't recall touching any config files, but hey, at least now I understand what's going on a bit better!

Comment: @JSONDerulo have some compassion, I am here because I don't know what's happening. Discussing meta stuff now isn't helping. I already explained why in one of my previous comments. I thank you for being here discussing this, but you're not helping. I cannot just magically replicate the same issue on stackblitz because even I don't understand what's happening. That is a fact that you'll have to accept if you want to help me solve this. I understand your point, but I must ask you to understand the facts that I'm giving here. Again, thank you for trying to help me out. I am kinda lost here.

Comment: Make sure to provide types to your template bound properties, so that the template checking can function properly. Also don't use `any` if you can provide a better type.

Comment: To add on, its better to create a type for your array for eg: `interface Item { title: string; content: string }` and then initialize it as `posts: Item[] = [...];`

Comment: Ooooh.... Ok. Thank you @MikeS. and @NicholasK. I'll keep that in mind when I start working on my own project. For now, the `:any` is enough for me to continue following the tutorial with as least deviation as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stackblitz doesn't show the problem because you haven't enabled `strict: true` in `tsconfig.json`

[Stackblitz that reproduces the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkw3qj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

To fix it, simply provide a type to `posts`, such as `{ title: string }[]`.

As a best practice, **Always** use types on template bound properties to avoid errors when using the properties in your template.

It is also absolutely fine to use the `strict` flag, it is fundamental for good typescript to keep yourself from omitting types or using implicit `any` (though you should never explicitly use it, either).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just the right and just enough information for a beginner like me.